# How can I make each chapter start on the right page?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, page, blank-page

I'm here to ask you how I can figure out where a chapter ends and add or not a blank page (if it ends on the right) or two (if it ends on the left).I know that there is a way to do it with even and odd numbers, but I never managed to try it: I thought about this code snippet, but even trying it it doesn't work.

Thanks to those who will help me :)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Where a chapter starts is usually defined by the document class being used, and starting on a right-hand page (preceded by a blank if appropriate) is default for the `book` class and quite a few others.

Comment: I believe the default of zero or one blank pages.  Are you looking to have one or two blank pages?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73591/107497 may have some help, but it definitely depends on what documentclass you're using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal example of your document. First of all: which documentclass are you using?